# Styling the last td in a table with css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to style the last TD in a table without using a CSS class on the particular TD.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <td>Five</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

table td 
{ 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I want the TD containing the text "Five" to not have a border but again, I do not want to use a class.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use class?

Comment: I want to keep the html static and be able to change the style without adding code or a bunch of css classes and IDs.

Comment: You could always just put `class="last"` on all the last cells and then never change it, and use it or not use it as your design calls for.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use relative rules:

```
table td + td + td + td + td {
  border: none;
}
```

This only works if the number of columns isn't determined at runtime.

Comment: It has its uses, especially if you, like this guy, don't want to have to change the HTML too much to support the CSS.

Comment: That works! Thanks. 

Yes the HTML is static and I don't want to add a bunch of css classes or id to style the cells.

Comment: Amusing trick, but it is less flexible than :last-child and doesn't work better on IE... Still worth remembering!

Comment: Why wouldn't `:last-child` be the obvious solution if you don't care about IE support? This is just ugly IMO...

Comment: What if I have a table with a lot of `<td>`? What if I use php to display data in table from MySQL Database? Do I need to put a lot of `td` to the CSS?

Answer (score 96):

The `:last-child` selector should do it, but it's [not supported in any version of IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

I'm afraid you have no choice but to use a class.

Comment: You spoke too soon, apparently there was a hack to avoid using a class =)

Comment: Not entirely true, >IE8 does support this, but is not well adopted yet. If you can live without IE8 support (which OP seems to be fine with), this is the best solution.

Comment: A bit out of date. Works great!

Answer (score 43):

You can use the `:last-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
tr > td:last-of-type {
    /* styling here */
}
```

See [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-of-type) for more info and compatibility with the different browsers.
Check out the [W3C CSS guidelines](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) for more info.

Answer (score 31):

you could use the last-child psuedo class

```
table tr td:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

This will style the last td only. It's not fully supported yet so it may be unsuitable

Comment: That'll style the last column, not row.

Comment: Which is what the OP requested, sorry if my description was slightly out.

Answer (score 23):

try with:

```
tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border:none;
    /*any other style*/
}
```

this will only affect the very last td element in the table, assuming is the only one (else, you'll just have to identify your table). Though, is very general, and it will adapt to the last TD if you add more content to your  table. So if it is a particular case

```
td:nth-child(5){
    border:none;
}
```

should be enough.

Comment: Please provide more information and details of how this solves the question. This will help the OP and other future searchers.

Comment: Perfect. Helps a lot with styling responsive tables. tr:last-child td:last-child == last tr in table, last td in tr

Answer (score 16):

If you are already using javascript take a look at jQuery.  It supports a browser independent "last-child" selector and you can do something like this.

```
$("td:last-child").css({border:"none"})
```

Comment: no, last-child means the last child of the parent, so my selector says "give me the last child of the row"

Comment: Thanks, I used it to bold a Total line in table. Very easy.

Comment: For many cases this works perfectly, but just beware if you are changing classes, remember that this will set the style on that item once, and that property won't change dynamically with CSS class changes anymore.

Comment: I think nickf is right. From what I tested and the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/ .

Comment: @Code, Yes I think you are correct. When I wrote this answer originally the documentation was a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is the only viable way to do this client side (that is, CSS won't help you). In jQuery:

```
$("table td:last").css("border", "none");
```

Comment: One down side to this is that it breaks the content/style/behaviour model.

Comment: using jQuery to add a classname that you can then style with CSS is semantic. e.g. jQuery('#shopping-cart-totals-table tfoot tr:last-child').addClass('last-row')

Answer (score 4):

You can use the :last-of-type to catch last column of your table.

```
<style>
.table > tbody > tr > td:last-of-type {
    /* Give your style Here; */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the col element as specified in HTML 4.0 ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-COL)). It works in every browser. You can give it an ID or a class or an inline style. only caveat is that it affects the whole column across all rows. Example:

```
<table>
    <col />
    <col width="50" />
    <col id="anId" />
    <col class="whatever" />
    <col style="border:1px solid #000;" />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>Five</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My example is inverse of what you wanted to do but you get what I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, provided the table is created either statically or dynamically prior to the following being executed:

```
$("table tr td:not(:last-child)").css({ "border-right":"1px solid #aaaaaa" });
```

Just adds a right border to every cell in a table row except the last cell.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but using <tfoot> might help you achieve what you need, and of course you can style tfoot.

Comment: no it won't. he's talking about the last CELL not the last ROW.

Answer (score 1):

For IE, how about using a CSS expression:

```
<style type="text/css">
table td { 
  h: expression(this.style.border = (this == this.parentNode.lastChild ? 'none' : '1px solid #000' ) );
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to do this too and found this, could be useful for other people:

```
#table td:last-of-type { border: none; }
```

Note that it's not supported by IE either.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that will add border for all the nodes and will remove the border for the last node(TD).

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {  
        font-family:arial;font-size: 8pt;  
    }  
    table td{
        border-right: #666 1px solid
    }  

    table td {  
        h: expression(this.style.border = (this == this.parentNode.lastChild ? 'none' : 'border-right:  0px solid' ) );  
    }  
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Home</td>
        <td>sunil</td>
        <td>Kumar</td>
        <td>Rayadurg</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>Six</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Enjoy ...

I want the same instead of border I wanted it using images ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a different approach.. and this would work for tables that aren't static... basically use `<th>` instead of `<td>` for that column:

```
<style type="text/css">
 table td { border: 1px solid black; }
 table th { border: 0px; }
<style>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Four</td>
      <th>Five</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```