# Is it possible to globally text-align a table column without specifying a class in each row?

Tags: jquery, css

Wondering what the best way to make this more efficient, perhaps with jQuery. I am ok with solutions not compliant with ie7, even lack of support for ie8 might be ok if necessary.

```
<style type="text/css">
.cal {text-align:center}
.ral {text-align:right}
</style>
<table>
 <th>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="ral">right</td>
 </th>
 <tr>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="ral">right</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="cal">center</td>
  <td>left</td>
  <td class="ral">right</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a class to the fifth td in each row using jQuery, and style the class to align text to the right.

Alternatively (and the way I do it) is using the [nth child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child).

```
tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    text-align: center;
}

tr td:nth-child(5) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

it's not compatible with IE 8.0, but it is a lot simpler than a JavaScript based solution.

Comment: This will work, based on the tip I found a great solution that has broader support for ie by applying the style with jQuery (only when using ie). There is even a jsfiddle demo to accompany the solution  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3951427/1101267)

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
table td { text-align: center; }
table td:last-child { text-align: right; }
```

This isn't supported by IE8- unfortunately. Another alternative is using JavaScript (e.g. jQuery, since you've tagged this post with it):

```
$(function(){ $('table tr').each(function(){ $('td:last', this).css({textAlign: 'right'}); } )}
```

This question seems to be well-accepted, although it's as ugly a hack as you can get: [Styling the last td in a table with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359821/styling-the-last-td-in-a-table-with-css)

Finally, you could cheat a little and have your last column's cell as a `<th>` element and then style it easily with:

```
table th { text-align: right; }
```

It wouldn't necessarily be semantically correct but it's another quick and easy option. I'm assuming the existing `<th>` elements in your original post are typos.

Comment: I think `:last-child` has slightly better compatibility than `:nth-child`, +1 for sportsmanship.

Comment: I think they're about the same. Ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#CSS3

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td:first-child').css('text-align', 'left');
$('td:nth-child(2)').css('text-align', 'center');
$('td:last-child').css('text-align', 'right');
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/ for other filters

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
td:first-child, td:first-child + td + td {
  text-align: center;
}
td:first-child + td + td + td + td {
  text-align: right;
}
</style>
<table>
<col align=center>
<col align=left>
<col align=center>
<col align=left>
<col align=right>
```

The style sheet works on reasonably new browsers. I have omitted the rules that set alignment to left, as that’s the default for `td`, but you may need to add such rules if other stylesheets may affect the alignment.

The `col` tags act as a backup: they use a method that should not work, by the specifications, but actually works on old versions of IE (as well as on newer versions when in Quirks Mode).