# Modifying nth child for table cells

Tags: css

This CSS rule works fine:

```
.TabSymbols tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2; }
```

Every other row has a background color.

Now imagine a table with four columns. Every table cell in the third and fourth column has the class "Date"...

```
<td class="Date">
```

The following style is applied to .Date:

```
.Date { background: #666; color: #fff; }
```

But here's the catch: I don't want every cell with class Date to have a background color. Rather, I want the styles to correspond with the first rule listed above. So the first two cells in every even-numbered row will have the background color #f2f2f2, while the last two cells will have the background #666. The odd-numbered rows will be a solid white, or whatever the table's background color is.

I tried these rules without success:

```
.TabSymbols tr:nth-child(even) td.Date { background-color: #666; }
.TabSymbols tr:nth-child(even).Date { background-color: #666; }
```

I also took a cue from [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342168/difficulties-with-application-of-nth-of-child-to-table-cells) and tried this:

```
tr td.Date:nth-child(2) { background-color: #666; color: #fff; }​
```

Maybe I could somehow use the col function with tr:nth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either apply the `.Date` background on `tr:nth-child(odd)` or `tr:not(:nth-child(even))`

```css
.TabSymbols tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #f2f2f2; }
/*.TabSymbols tr:nth-child(odd) .Date { background: #666; color: #fff; }*/
.TabSymbols tr:not(:nth-child(even)) .Date { background: #666; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<table class="TabSymbols">
  <tr>
    <td class="Date">foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td class="Date">foo</td>
    <td class="Date">foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td class="Date">foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td class="Date">foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```