# How can I apply style to each last rows before specific class in a table?

Tags: html, css

I need to style the last row in each group (that is Row 3, Row 5 and Row 8). My css sample only apply style to Row 8.

Code:

```css
tr.row:last-child td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="group">
    <td>Group 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="group">
    <td>Group 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="group">
    <td>Group 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wrap each group in a <div></div>

Comment: You refer this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359821/styling-the-last-td-in-a-table-with-css )

Comment: @Gajanan Let me know how does it help.

Comment: Please re-open, this can be solved by slightly altering HTML, without having to look up previous siblings