# Javascript get the last td of a table to remove/delete it

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get the last td of a table and remove it? It should be only JS, no jquery.

I tried this:

```
e.target.parentNode.querySelector("td:lastcell").remove();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about that attempt failed?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: e.target.parentNode.querySelector("td:lastcell").remove();

Comment: So what exactly is `e.target`?  If it's a not a `td` (eg a div in a td or button/input) then `.parentNode` will not give you the tr.

Comment: `:lastcell` is not a valid pseudo-class, as far as I know.

Comment: Rather than `:lastcell` (which doesn't appear to be a valid selector) - you can use `td:last-of-type` or `td:last-child`.     But this will depend on whether you start at the table or tr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling the last td in a table with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359821/styling-the-last-td-in-a-table-with-css)

Comment: I have a cancel Button and I want to remove the last td, when you click on them, but lastcell and last-type-of doesnt work. Here the code: 
 <template id="subject-template">
    <div class="subject-wrapper">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input class="marks" name="mark" type="text" placeholder="mark">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

---JS---
 markContainer.querySelector("button.cancel-mark").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector("table td:last-of-type").remove();

Comment: Are you sure it's the last-of-type not working and not the `e.target.parentNode`?  Need more context/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var t = document.getElementById("test"); // The table
var lastTD = t.querySelector("TD:last-of-type");
console.log ("Text: " + lastTD.innerText);
```

```html
<table id="test">
<tr>
<td>A</td>
<td>B</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.children` should get you all the children as an array you can get the last child simply by `element.children[element.children.length -1]` and do whatever you want with it.
Also if your table has an `id` you can get the last `td` by using `document.querySelect('#table-id td:last-child')` or use `document.querySelectAll('#table-id td:last-child')` to get all the last `td`s

Comment: It removes the first td not the last by mine. Here the code:
marksContainer.querySelector("button.cancel-mark").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.target.parentNode.querySelector("table td:last-child").remove();

Comment: It's vague what you've posted with element.children. But if this is on a table, this is going to get you the last row, not the last cell. Also, if the table has a TBODY / THEAD, doing element.children is a brittle solution